# Why "rake test" and "rake test:functionals" give different results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rake, fixtures, zeus

I've had a weird event of having `rake test` and `rake test:functionals` producing different results on a Rails 3 app that uses fixtures to insert test database records. The first group was failing on one of the controller tests, while the other one was successfully passing.

I also tried to run the failing test with `ruby -I test path/to/file` and `zeus test path/to/file`, but those runs were successful. The issue was reproduced on different machines. The test was failing because of the state of the test database, which seemed impossible to me when I looked at the fixtures.

Strangely enough, the issue disappeared the next day and I no longer can reproduce it. What could be the cause of such a problem and how to avoid it?

Comment: always make sure your db is in a clean state

Comment: Hey @diego.greyrobot, how should I do that if using factories isn't an option on this app?